# Error generate rig in (rigify) after removing tongue and bottom teeth bone

Tags: rigging, rigify

when editing the human metarig, I **delete bottom teeth bone and tongue bone**. Because I don't need them. When I generate rig, I get error message. So I recreate the with "**basic.super_copy**", rename, reparent and adjust their layer in relations tab. But i still get the error message and it won't generate the rig.

The error message is like this:
**Generation has thrown an exception: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "ORG-tongue" not found'**

How to fix this so i can generate the rig?

Comment: Did you delete them before or after generating the new rig from the metarig? Don't ever delete them beforehand. It will always be bad. But then, even deleting them afterwards can sometimes cause problems. It might be better to not delete bones you don't want to use, and simply uncheck the Deform box under the Bone tab in the Properties panel for any bone you essentially want to "disable." Any such bone will no longer affect the mesh.

Comment: before generating the rig. Thanks for the info that I can uncheck the deform box.
so, can I fix this problem? I try to recreate the bones and rename them but it seems like that doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Don't recreate and/or rename the bones either. At least, not before generating the rig. I seem to recall this is also problematic. After generating, it is probably okay to rename them, or even add new ones. But it's still risky to delete existing ones, or to "recreate" them, as you say, if by this you mean, "replace existing ones with new ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!
So, you create "**faces.super_face**" in rigify buttons tab.
delete all the face bone except the one that you accidentally delete. In my case, those are tongue bones and bottom teeth bone. Then, you parent them back to face bone, reposition them and click "generate rig" in object mode. It successfully generate the rig.

Notes for others, never delete any bones from the face rig. if you don't want to use them just deactivate "deform" in bones properties. *credits goes to R-800 for the info!!

Shout out and thanks to R-800 for helping me!!